# How to Make a toggle switch that submits data

Tags: javascript, html

Good day! I am writing a code that should allow me to use a switch toggle button to submit the form.

For instance, the default value is "light" and when the user clicks the toggle button, it submits a value="dark".

I am unable to achieve getting the toggle to submit. When I click it, it does nothing but just switches.

My HTML toggle form is

```html
<form method="post">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="dark">       <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because checkboxes don't submit forms. Submit buttons do.

Comment: You can trigger submit event in javascript / jQuery for the form using onChange event on checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `submit()` method on the `<form>` element to submit using JavaScript.

```js
function clickFn(event) {
  const checkbox = event.currentTarget;
  checkbox.value = checkbox.checked ? 'dark' : 'light';
  event.currentTarget.closest('form').submit()
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="myForm">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="dark" onclick="clickFn(event)">       <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: It Finally Worked. Thanks for your help. I however removed this line checkbox.value = checkbox.checked ? 'dark' : 'light'; so that the defined value can be passed, rather than just dark or  light

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery or even vanilla javascript to trigger form submit event on click or on check of the check box.

Sample HTML

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="dark" id="myCheckBox">       <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Relevant jQuery Code

```
$("#myCheckBox").change(function() {
  if(this.checked === true) {
     $("#myForm").submit();
  }
})
```

This is just and example, you can modify as per your requirements

For reference [jQuery Change Event handler](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

**Update**
You haven’t defined any action to the form. And I fixed the typo `#myCheckbox` => `#myCheckBox`

Comment: There was a typo in `#myCheckbox` should be `#myCheckBox`